# windbg setting conditional breakpoint

Tags: debugging, windbg, breakpoints

I want to put a conditional breakpoint in windbg.

For example lets say LoadLibrary API.

How can I put breakpoint such that it should it whenever user32.dll get loaded.

```
> x kernel32!LoadLibraryW
```

It will give some address [XXXX]

Now I can put breakpoint as

```
> bu [XXXX]
```

but this will hit for all calls to LoadLibraryW.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can not set a conditional breakpoint on a user32.dll since it's being mapped into the address space relatively early and the initial debugger's breakpoint triggers after that (as far as i know).

provided you can track the moment user32.dll is loaded, you can override a module break like this:

```
sxe ld user32.dll
```

what you could do is have your app get started by a boostrapper application and then have windows debugger break on user32.dll load. just use -o command-line option or `.childdbg 1` extension call to initiate debugging of child processes and have it started with cmd.exe, for instance:

```
windbg -c "sxe ld user32.dll;g" -o cmd.exe /C yourapp.exe
```

Comment: Well I was just giving example of user32.dll, it could be any dll. I want to break at loading of a particular dll , but windbg loads all dlls so fast that I am not able to find out the who is loading that dll.

Comment: just make debugger halt at its initial breakpoint (do not use -g command line option) and set module break condition like shown above, substituting user32 with a dll name of your choice or do not specify any names to make it break on load of every module (courtesy of debugger.chm).

Comment: I found another way.We can do a string comparison.If string is user32.dll the break .
we can set conditional breakpoint like 

>bu XXXXXX ";as /mu ${/v:MyAlias} poi(@esp+0x4*1); .if ( $spat( \"${MyAlias}\", \"*User32*\" ) != 0 ) {;.echo  *** LoadLibrary CALLED *** ;.printf \"%mu\\n\", dwo (ESP + 0x04*1);.echo } .else { g }"

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by the text and header in your question. But assuming you want to set a conditional breakpoint you should take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc267482.aspx) cause it goes into plenty of detail on that subject.