# How DLL's resolve its IAT?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, portable-executable

When i load dll in my process, how that dll resolve address of function that it imports ?
I tried to set breakpoint on GetProcAddress and LdrGetProcedureAddress but it doesnt break there.

Please someone explain.

Comment: Well, that's not what happens.  It is the Windows loader that takes care of it.  It doesn't need to use GetProcAddress, it has direct access to the raw data in the import tables.  This needs to be fast.

Comment: Are you trying to do something specific or are you just curious?

Comment: If you would like to break when a DLL is loaded, you can use windbg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366051/windbg-setting-conditional-breakpoint

Comment: I want to hook function CreateWindowExW/A, the main problem is that the function is not directly called from the main executable module but is called mainly from comctl32.dll,shlwapi.dll and etc, i tried to do IAT/EAT hooking but it didnt worked. The Rohitab API Monitor(rohitab.com) is successfully hooking that function but i dont see how its doing that....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the DLL is loaded the loader will update all addresses if required to reflect the base address where the DLL is loaded.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985014.aspx :

> When creating a DLL, the linker assumes that the DLL will load at a
>   particular address. Certain pieces of the code and data contain
>   hardcoded addresses that are only correct if the DLL loads at the
>   preferred address. However, at runtime it's possible that the
>   operating system may have to load the DLL at a different memory
>   location.
>
> To handle the situation where the OS has to move the DLL, the linker
>   adds base relocations to the DLL. Base relocations are addresses that
>   require modification so that they contain the correct address for
>   where the DLL loaded in memory. The more base relocations a DLL has,
>   the more time the OS needs to process them and to load the DLL. A
>   properly based DLL loads at its preferred address, and can skip
>   processing the base relocation records.

It's more common these days that a DLL's base address is randomized as a security measure, the above article predates that.  Also see:

[Relocation (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computer_science%29)

[Portable Executable (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#Relocations)